# While dates are less than or equal to Redshift join

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with data as follows:

```
+--------+---------------+------------+------------+
| emp_id |  emp_job_nm   | start_date |  end_date  |
+--------+---------------+------------+------------+
| abc123 | cool_dude_1   | 03/02/2002 | 03/03/2020 |
| abc123 | cool_dude_2   | 03/03/2020 | 03/26/2020 |
| abc123 | not_cool_1    | 03/26/2020 | 04/27/2020 |
| abc123 | almost_cool_1 | 04/27/2020 | 05/27/2020 |
| def345 | cool_dude_1   | 05/27/2020 | 06/26/2020 |
| def345 | cool_dude_1   | 01/02/2020 | 01/03/2020 |
| def345 | cool_dude_2   | 01/03/2020 | 01/26/2020 |
| def345 | not_cool_1    | 02/26/2020 | 03/27/2020 |
| def345 | almost_cool_1 | 03/27/2020 | 07/27/2020 |
| def345 | cool_dude_1   | 07/27/2020 | 08/26/2020 |
+--------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

Then I have a full calendar table that gives me dates for each day of each year between 1990 - 2050

the outcome I am trying for is

```
+--------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| emp_id | emp_job_nm  | start_date |  end_date  |  cal_date  |
+--------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| abc123 | cool_dude_1 | 03/02/2002 | 03/03/2020 | 03/02/2020 |
| abc123 | cool_dude_1 | 03/02/2002 | 03/03/2020 | 03/03/2020 |
| abc123 | cool_dude_2 | 03/03/2020 | 03/26/2020 | 03/04/2020 |
| abc123 | cool_dude_2 | 03/03/2020 | 03/26/2020 | 03/05/2020 |
| abc123 | cool_dude_2 | 03/03/2020 | 03/26/2020 | 03/06/2020 |
+--------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

essentially, while the end date is < cal date give me that id and job name.  One thing to note is that this is a join because these are two separate tables.  So the first 4 columns are in an employee table and the cal_date is in a calendar table.  Extend this out, each employee by job title for each day as long as the end date is <= the cal date.

getting the join right and de-duping is kicking my butt.

I have tried a few different RANK OVER functions, but can't get the de-dupe working.

```
RANK () OVER ( PARTITION BY emp_id, emp_job_nm, end_date ORDER BY cal_date ASC ) AS rownum
RANK () OVER ( PARTITION BY emp_id, emp_job_nm, end_date ORDER BY end_date ASC ) AS rownum
```

as part of

```
dates AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE(calendar_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS cal_date
    FROM iso_calendar.date_dim
)

SELECT *, RANK () OVER ( PARTITION BY emp_id, emp_job_nm, end_date ORDER BY cal_date ASC ) AS rownum
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN emp e ON ON e.end_date <= cal_date AND e.start_date < e.end_date
```

Comment: What happens to the rest of the dates?

Comment: Let me clarify the outcome is just a small sample, I need the output to show all the dates.

Comment: And what is the logic for de-duping?

Comment: ummm as long as the start date and end date are < = the calendar date.  So, like in the example cool_dude_1 should exist on cal_date 03/02/2020 and 03/03/2020.  Then cool_dude_2 starts on 03/04/2020 until 03/26?2020, etc.

Comment: One more thing to keep in mind is that this is a table of more than one employee.  I can expand the example if needed to make sure that is understood.

Comment: Can I ask why are are doing this expansion?  Likely to compute some summary (active jobs on any day).  Since you are using Redshift I'd guess that the table of employees could be large and the dates table goes back years.  As these things get large the expansion of the data will explode.  You may run into performance issues when you do this.  There are better ways when the data gets big

Answer (score 0):

I think fixing the `join` conditions does what you want:

```
with dates AS (
      SELECT TO_DATE(calendar_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS cal_date
      FROM iso_calendar.date_dim
    )    
SELECT emp.*, d.cal_date
FROM emp e JOIN
     dates d
     ON e.end_date <= d.cal_date AND d.cal_date < e.end_date
```